# Showing Users' Profile Pictures from AWS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm totally new to AWS and I want to understand how some key concepts work before starting to build.  I found this tutorial for uploading images directly to AWS in node JS:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node#uploading-directly-to-s3

In my webapp I am using MongoDB, and each User (user Schema) has the ability to change their profile picture.  At a high level, I was thinking once the user selects a new picture and hits save, I would follow the steps above to upload the new image directly to an AWS 'bucket'.

How would I then render it back on the User's profile page? Do I need to use a database on the AWS side (and skip the mongodb part I had for my app) to associate each user with a profile picture?  I understand the "saving to AWS" part, but what's not clear is how to retrieve/render the image (right after saving to AWS) in a way where it is associated with the User. Here is my mongoose User schema:

```
'use strict';

var crypto = require('crypto');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var recipeSchema = require('./recipe.js').schema;
//need the objectID, see: https://gist.github.com/fwielstra/1025038
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var userSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String
  },
  password: String,
  resetPasswordToken: String,
  resetPasswordExpires: Date,
  //image: String ---> replacing this url with AWS
  picture: ObjectId,
  name: String,
  facebook: {
    id: String,
    token: String,
    pictures: String
  },

  emailSubscription: Boolean,


   recipeBox: [{
    id: ObjectId,
    done: Boolean
  }]
});


var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would save a record in a database associating the image with the user. You could use any database for this, MongoDB or DynamoDB or MySQL or anything else you want to use. There's nothing special going on here that would require you to use some special database type on AWS to store the image location on S3.

Then you could configure S3 to serve the bucket as a static website. When you want to display the image you would simply use the S3 URL of the image.

**Edit to answer questions in comments:**

You should read that Heroku tutorial you linked. See this section:

> You may wish to assign another, customised name to the object instead
>   of using the one that the file is already named with, which is useful
>   for preventing accidental overwrites in the S3 bucket. This name could
>   be related to the ID of the user’s account, for example.

That's where you would control the name of the file stored on S3, possibly by using the user ID as the name. In that same block of code you could update your database with the location of the user's profile image.

Comment: I see. and that URL would have the userID (or some other identifier to the user) in it?

Comment: The URL would only have the user ID in it if you put the user ID in the file name. S3 doesn't know anything about your app's users so it's not going to do that for you automatically.

Comment: @Mark B I am storing the aws link of the image in my database after it's uploaded, but my link is getting expired(even after removing the expires parameter while uploading).

Comment: @sacDahal please don't post entirely new questions as comments on other questions.